# Kill Rollback SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions, kill, rollback

I've tried to kill a rollback SPID and get a message as seen below. Please assist

```
transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: I require a method to kill a rollback as Kill (SPID) doesn't work for rollback commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can use `KILL SPID STATUSONLY` but never do that cause if you kill a rollback process then your DB state will become inconsistent. Rather wait for the rollback process to complete.

Use `sp_who` and `sp_who2` to see what's the rollback process is doing. I mean it's I/O information.